# Calculating numbers in UITextField

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

This may be a very easy question for some of you, but I really would appreciate some help. I am trying to divide one UITextField number by another and when you push the button, it displays it in the third UITextField. Here's what I have so far but get the Invalid operands to binary expression (UITextField *' and 'UITextField *') error.

and yes, i know this is a very simple question, but an answer would really help me. Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)calculateButton:(id)sender;
{
    kdField = firstNum / secondNum;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the third UITextField to the firstNum / secondNum when the user presses the calculateButton

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Assume `KdField, FirstNum` and `secondNum` are all global UITextfield.

Remove the semi-colon after `(id)sender`

In your buttonAction try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)calculateButton:(id)sender{
    kdField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[firstNum.text intValue] / [secondNum.text intValue]];
}
```

I put %f since division can have decimal places

Answer (score 4):

Assuming kdField is your UITextField:

```
kdField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(firstNum/secondNum)];//or use %f if you're dividing floats
```

Additionally, if firstNum and secondNum are in UITextFields you'd have to grab the int values with something like:

```
NSString *firstNumString = firstNumField.text;
int firstNum = [firstNumString intValue];
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer to mark as solved (its the little check mark next to the answer)